# Error when creating a new Customer - MVC ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I get the following error when I fill out my form in my MVC Application:

```
UpdateException was unhandled by user code

Unable to update the EntitySet 'Customer' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

My Customer table has: **ID (PK), Name, Age, Address and a TimeStamp.**

The form only allows Name and Address to be filled out (don't know why - I'm new to MVC, ADO.NET btw)

This is my code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
    {
        customer.ID = 5;
        db.Customers.AddObject(customer);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

I am leaving customer.ID = 5 as a hard coded temp solution for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ID` is your primary key, Why you are updating that ? You should be updating the rest of the properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
{
    customer.Name= "New name";
    db.Customers.AddObject(customer);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **primary key** in your Customer Table ?
This error originates when you do not have primary key on table or when your entity set is mapped with database view.